# Unable to download dependencies as machine doesn't have internet connection

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to install Perl using `yum` but unable to resolve dependencies as my machine is not connected to internet. But I have all dependencies on my machine in the same directory where the perl package is.

Could you please help me how can I install perl ?
Please refer to logs below:

```
 [root@linux-vm1 ~]# yum install perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
    This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package perl.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Socket) >= 1.3 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Scalar::Util) >= 1.10 for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl-macros for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl-libs for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(threads::shared) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(threads) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(constant) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Time::Local) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Time::HiRes) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Storable) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Socket) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Scalar::Util) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Simple::XHTML) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Simple::Search) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Getopt::Long) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Filter::Util::Call) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Temp) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Spec::Unix) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Spec::Functions) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Spec) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(File::Path) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Exporter) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Cwd) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Carp) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libperl.so()(64bit) for package: 4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package perl-Carp.noarch 0:1.26-244.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Exporter.noarch 0:5.68-3.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-File-Path.noarch 0:2.09-2.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-File-Temp.noarch 0:0.23.01-3.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Filter.x86_64 0:1.49-3.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Getopt-Long.noarch 0:2.40-3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Usage) >= 1.14 for package: perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Text::ParseWords) for package: perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch
    ---> Package perl-PathTools.x86_64 0:3.40-5.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Pod-Simple.noarch 1:3.28-4.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Escapes) >= 1.04 for package: 1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Encode) for package: 1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch
    ---> Package perl-Scalar-List-Utils.x86_64 0:1.27-248.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Socket.x86_64 0:2.010-4.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Storable.x86_64 0:2.45-3.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Time-HiRes.x86_64 4:1.9725-3.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Time-Local.noarch 0:1.2300-2.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-constant.noarch 0:1.27-2.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-libs.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-threads.x86_64 0:1.87-4.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-threads-shared.x86_64 0:1.43-6.el7 will be installed
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package perl-Encode.x86_64 0:2.51-7.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Pod-Escapes.noarch 1:1.04-294.el7_6 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-Pod-Usage.noarch 0:1.63-3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(Pod::Text) >= 3.15 for package: perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: perl-Pod-Perldoc for package: perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch
    ---> Package perl-Text-ParseWords.noarch 0:3.29-4.el7 will be installed
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package perl-Pod-Perldoc.noarch 0:3.20-4.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(parent) for package: perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
    --> Processing Dependency: perl(HTTP::Tiny) for package: perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
    ---> Package perl-podlators.noarch 0:2.5.1-3.el7 will be installed
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package perl-HTTP-Tiny.noarch 0:0.033-3.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package perl-parent.noarch 1:0.225-244.el7 will be installed
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    
    Dependencies Resolved
    
    =======================================================================================================================================
     Package                                 Arch                    Version                              Repository                  Size
    =======================================================================================================================================
    Installing:
     perl                                    x86_64                  4:5.16.3-294.el7_6                   localrepo                  8.0 M
    Installing for dependencies:
     perl-Carp                               noarch                  1.26-244.el7                         localrepo                   19 k
     perl-Encode                             x86_64                  2.51-7.el7                           localrepo                  1.5 M
     perl-Exporter                           noarch                  5.68-3.el7                           localrepo                   28 k
     perl-File-Path                          noarch                  2.09-2.el7                           localrepo                   27 k
     perl-File-Temp                          noarch                  0.23.01-3.el7                        localrepo                   56 k
     perl-Filter                             x86_64                  1.49-3.el7                           localrepo                   76 k
     perl-Getopt-Long                        noarch                  2.40-3.el7                           localrepo                   56 k
     perl-HTTP-Tiny                          noarch                  0.033-3.el7                          localrepo                   38 k
     perl-PathTools                          x86_64                  3.40-5.el7                           localrepo                   83 k
     perl-Pod-Escapes                        noarch                  1:1.04-294.el7_6                     localrepo                   51 k
     perl-Pod-Perldoc                        noarch                  3.20-4.el7                           localrepo                   87 k
     perl-Pod-Simple                         noarch                  1:3.28-4.el7                         localrepo                  216 k
     perl-Pod-Usage                          noarch                  1.63-3.el7                           localrepo                   27 k
     perl-Scalar-List-Utils                  x86_64                  1.27-248.el7                         localrepo                   36 k
     perl-Socket                             x86_64                  2.010-4.el7                          localrepo                   49 k
     perl-Storable                           x86_64                  2.45-3.el7                           localrepo                   77 k
     perl-Text-ParseWords                    noarch                  3.29-4.el7                           localrepo                   14 k
     perl-Time-HiRes                         x86_64                  4:1.9725-3.el7                       localrepo                   45 k
     perl-Time-Local                         noarch                  1.2300-2.el7                         localrepo                   24 k
     perl-constant                           noarch                  1.27-2.el7                           localrepo                   19 k
     perl-libs                               x86_64                  4:5.16.3-294.el7_6                   localrepo                  688 k
     perl-macros                             x86_64                  4:5.16.3-294.el7_6                   localrepo                   44 k
     perl-parent                             noarch                  1:0.225-244.el7                      localrepo                   12 k
     perl-podlators                          noarch                  2.5.1-3.el7                          localrepo                  112 k
     perl-threads                            x86_64                  1.87-4.el7                           localrepo                   49 k
     perl-threads-shared                     x86_64                  1.43-6.el7                           localrepo                   39 k
    
    Transaction Summary
    =======================================================================================================================================
    Install  1 Package (+26 Dependent packages)
    
    Total download size: 11 M
    Installed size: 36 M
    Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
    Downloading packages:
    
    
    Error downloading packages:
      perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      1:perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-threads-shared-1.43-6.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      4:perl-libs-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Time-Local-1.2300-2.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-constant-1.27-2.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Storable-2.45-3.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      4:perl-Time-HiRes-1.9725-3.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      4:perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Socket-2.010-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-threads-1.87-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-podlators-2.5.1-3.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      1:perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-294.el7_6.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      4:perl-macros-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      1:perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Filter-1.49-3.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
      perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
    
    [root@linux-vm1 ~]#
```

Comment: Is connecting to the internet an option on your machine? This may be the easiest method.

Comment: When you say you have all the dependencies, do you mean you have a bunch of perl-Foo-Bar.rpm.gz files or a bunch of foo-bar.tar.gz files, or what?

Comment: Can you share what the local file which you are trying to install is?

Comment: @TimurShtatland No not possible to connect machine to internet.

Comment: @DaveMitchell i have all. I extracted the  perl package from another machine where it is already installed . The only issue is during yum install files are getting downloaded over internet ( which i dont have) and server is not looking for dependencies in local yum package  directory.

Comment: @FarhadBharucha perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64.rpm
I am trying to install above package with yum .

Comment: try something like yum localinstall /path/to/file.rpm for each file like perl-Carp.noarch 0:1.26-244.el7.rpm. Then install perl.

Comment: @DaveMitchell Same issue with localinstall too.

Comment: @RajKatiyar you have given exactly no detail, which isn't helpful. So: what exactly happens when you run yum localinstall /path/to/perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch.rpm for example? What error do you get?

Comment: @DaveMitchell its the same error when i run yum install perl

Comment: @RajKatiyar. What EXACT error do you get when you run the EXACT command I suggested above? Cut and paste the output please.

Comment: @DaveMitchell Output is too long so i am pasting in numbers of posts.

Comment: @DaveMitchell since output was too long i have pasted it as an answer . Please check the bottom thread

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ISO image of your Linux distribution (which should have perl) to work as a repository.

Mount the ISO:
`mount -o loop,ro /path/to/linux.iso /mnt/linux`

Create a repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/iso.repo:

```
    [ISO]
    name=Local ISO
    baseurl=file:///mnt/linux
```

Comment: I have already configured the yum. Please read the problem again

Answer (score 0):

It seems you aren't giving a local path.

You can try running:

```
yum install ./perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64.rpm
```

or

```
 yum localinstall ./perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64.rpm
```

That might solve your problem

Comment: Hi Farhad, Still the same issue :(

Comment: @RajKatiyar  Maybe install the dependency packages first and then try installing perl and see what happens

Comment: Again same, Dependencies are trying to download other dependencies via internet . I just dont know why its trying to download via internet when i have all the files on my server locally.